# error bar plotting with some range

Tags: error-propagation

In the following pic I want to show the error bar plotting with some given data: Y axis: 5.86*10^(-8) with error .58*10^(-8) and X axis: 0.1 to 2 (that means there is a range), 2.56*10^(-8) with error 0.25*10^(-8) and X axis: 2 to 5.0, etc. What command I will use?[image]

Comment: Have you seen ErrorBarPlots and ErrorListPlot?

Comment: Yes. But How I can show these given data mentioned above in the same plot.

Comment: Your description is not clear form me, and your picture does not make it clear. May be you can think about explaining what you are after in a more clear way?

Comment: Actually I have plotted this two scenarios using suitable commands. I want to add the data mentioned above by plotting error bar  in the same graph. I don't understand how it is possible.